# WHERE MySQL clause not working in Drupal 6

Tags: database

I am writing a Drupal Module and I have encountered a problem. This is my code:

```
$query3 = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid=19");
var_dump(db_result($query3));
```

It currently returns: `bool(false)`

Now when I run this query in phpmyadmin it returns the desired nid (47) - no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you run `$query3 = db_query("COUNT(nid) FROM {node}"); var_dump(db_result($query3));`? That will tell you if it's the `WHERE` clause or something else

Comment: This code returns: bool(false)

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in that it should be `SELECT COUNT(nid)...`. I've just run that revised query on a D6 site and received the count of the nodes in the node table. If it's not working for you you've got something really wrong in your installation. Is the site actually functioning ok other than this?

Comment: Ok - the result for this is:  string(1) "4" - so it is counting the nodes

Comment: OK so `db_query()` is working fine, and you have 4 nodes in your node table. I would go into the table in PHPMyAdmin and make doubly sure that the `uid` column has `19` in it for at least one of the nodes

Comment: Clive you are a legend! db selection error...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$query3 = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = '%d'", 19);
```

this is the proper way to handle variables in the db_query, as it prevents sql injection.

```
//grab the current user
global $user;
$query3 = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = '%d'", $user->uid);
```

Comment: I tried this: $query3 = db_query("SELECT nid FROM [node} WHERE uid = '%d', 19");      It still returns the same error...

Comment: I also tried the edited version: $query3 = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = '%d'", 19);

Comment: try '%s', and see if that works

Comment: '%s' gives the same result.

Comment: The user ID is an integer; you don't use quotes surrounding %d, nor do you use %s.